# Discriminants and Weierstrass form of elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm confused by what appears to be contradictory information.

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107287/finiteness-of-elliptic-curves-of-a-given-conductor) post, the claim is made that

"Every elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ can be written in the form $y^{2}= x^{3}+ax+b$ where $a,b∈ \mathbb{Z}$ with discriminant $Δ=−16(4a^{3}+27b^{2})≠0$. So the number of elliptic curves of discriminant $D$ is bounded above by number of nontrivial pairs $(a,b)∈ \mathbb{Z}^{2}$ such that $D=−16(4a^{3}+27b^{2})$."

Is this true?  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120401/form-of-minimal-integral-weierstrass-equation-for-elliptic-curve-over-q-with-g) post gives an example of an elliptic curve with integer coefficients that is *not* isomorphic to any curve $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ for $A, B$ integers and discriminant equal to the original.   Isn't this in contradiction to the original claim?  That is, the curve in the second link would not be counted as a curve with its discriminant, right?

In fact, it seems to me (after plugging through the relevant changes of variables) that *most* curves of the form 
$$E: y^2 + a_{1} xy + a_{3} y = x^{3} + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{4}x + a_{6},$$ with discriminant $\Delta$

cannot be written in the form
$$ E' : y^{2} = x^{3} + Ax + B $$ with discriminant also $\Delta$ for some $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement:

> "The number of elliptic curves of discriminant $D$ is bounded above by
> number of nontrivial pairs $(a,b)∈ \mathbb{Z}^{2}$ such that
> $D=−16(4a^{3}+27b^{2})$."

is certainly false as stated. For example, the discriminant of the model for the curve $$E:y^2 + y = x^3 - x^2 - 10x - 20$$
is $-11^5$. Any model of the form $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ with integers $A,B$ has a discriminant of the form $D=-16(4a^3+27b^2)$. But the equation
$$-11^5 = -16(4a^3+27b^2)$$
is impossible in integers $a,b$ as the left hand side is odd and the right hand side is even.

One could salvage the statement above, however, and write something in a similar spirit. Going from a generic Weierstrass model to a short Weierstrass model means that the discriminant is multiplied, at worst, by $2^{12}3^{12}$. So one could say

> "The number of elliptic curves of discriminant $D$ is bounded above $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4$, where
>
> - $n_1$ is the number of non-trivial pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $D=-16(4a^3+27b^2)$,
> - $n_2$ is the number of non-trivial pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $2^{12}D=-16(4a^3+27b^2)$,
> - $n_3$ is the number of non-trivial pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $3^{12}D=-16(4a^3+27b^2)$, and
> - $n_4$ is the number of non-trivial pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $6^{12}D=-16(4a^3+27b^2)$."

and I believe this is a true statement.

Comment: Regarding "Going from a generic Weierstrass model to a short Weierstrass model means that the discriminant is multiplied, at worst, by $2^{12} 3^{12}$" Is this true?  I've only seen that going from one "short" Weierstrass model to another results in multiplying the discriminant by a $12$th power of $2, 3$ or $6$. In fact in Silverman (pages $42-43$ he gives that $y^{2} + a_{1}xy + a_{3}y = x^{3} + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{4}x + a_{6}$ is isomorphic to $y^{2} = x^{3} - 27c_{4}x - 54c_{6}$ but these two discriminants don't necessarily (and indeed it seems very rarely) differ by a twelfth power.

Comment: If you go from an equation of the form $y^2+Axy+By=f(x)$ to one of the form $Y^2=f(x)$, you need to do a change of the form $Y=y+(Ax+B)/2$. This may introduce a $2^{12}$ in the discriminant. If now you go from $y^2=x^3+Ax^2+Bx+C$ to $y^2=X^3+A'x+B'$, you need a change of the form $X=x-A/3$, and this may introduce a $3^{12}$ in the discriminant.

Comment: Okay, I had miscalculated something.  I now agree that what you wrote is true.  Thanks